# OpenCV process parts of an image

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to use a PNG with an alpha channel to 'mask' the current frame from a video stream.

My PNG has black pixels in the areas that I don't want processed and alpha in others - currently it's saved a 4 colours image with 4 channels, but it might as well be a binary image.

I'm doing background subtraction and contour finding on the image, so I imagine if I copy the black pixels from my 'mask' image into the current then there would be no contours found in the black areas. Is this a good approach? If so, how can I copy the black/non transparent pixels from one `cv::Mat` on top of the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing sounds to me like the usage of an image mask. It's odd that you'd do it in the alpha channel, when so many methods available in the OpenCV libraries support masking. Rather than use the alpha channel, why not create a separate binary image with non-zero values everywhere you'd like to find contours?

Depending on which algorithms you use, you are correct in your assumption that you would not find contours in the black pixeled areas. Unfortunately, I don't know of any efficient ways of copying pixels from one image to another, selectively, without getting into the nitty-gritty of the Mat structure, and iterating from byte to byte/pixel to pixel. Using the mask idea presented above with your pre-processing functions, and then sending the resulting binary image into findContours or the like, would allow you to both take advantage of the already well-written and optimized code of the OpenCV library, and keep more of your hair on your head, where it belongs ;).

Comment: See http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=copyto#void Mat::copyTo(OutputArray m, InputArray mask) const

Comment: Thanks, I did actually start to look through rows/columns and copy values :). Yes, am enjoying CV a lot so far, even though I'm to eager to play with everything, I should have a structure to my learning. Also, I've found another function that is handy: `cv::addWeighted`